# How can I start Kafka consumer with an HTTP request?

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, openshift

I'm trying to make a Web API in a Docker container that will be shipped into an OpenShift instance. The API has swagger and an HTTP POST method with the Kafka consumer settings params to start the consumer.

The API runs locally without issues but when I deploy it on OpenShift it return 504 after about 30 sec.

What I want is a looping request that listen to the consumer without breaking. So my question is my approach right or should I do it in another way? In that way how?

Some log info:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://xxxxxx/StartKafkaConsumer application/json-patch+json 175 

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1] 
Route matched with {action = "StartKafkaConsumer", controller = "NotificationManager"}. 
Executing action xxxxManager.API.Controllers.xxxxxManagerController.StartKafkaConsumer (xxxxManager.API) 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1] 
Executing action method xxxxxManager.API.Controllers.xxxxxManagerController.StartKafkaConsumer (xxxxManager.API) with arguments 
(xxxxManager.EventListeners.Kafka.DTO.KafkaInputConfigDTO) - Validation state: Valid
```

And:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")] public async Task<string> StartKafkaConsumer([FromBody] KafkaInputConfigDTO kafkaInputConfigDTO) { 
    return await _kafkaService.StartKafkaConsumer(kafkaInputConfigDTO); 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the app isn't being started correctly.  Is there any logging you can get out of OpenShift?

Comment: @Neil thanks for your answer, no the logs shows that the http post request goes right into the controller and the model validates without any problem.

Comment: Here comes some log: `info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://xxxxxx/StartKafkaConsumer application/json-patch+json 175

Comment: And: info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1] 
Route matched with {action = "StartKafkaConsumer", controller = "NotificationManager"}. 
Executing action xxxxManager.API.Controllers.xxxxxManagerController.StartKafkaConsumer (xxxxManager.API) 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1] 
Executing action method xxxxxManager.API.Controllers.xxxxxManagerController.StartKafkaConsumer (xxxxManager.API) with arguments 
(xxxxManager.EventListeners.Kafka.DTO.KafkaInputConfigDTO) - Validation state: Valid`

Comment: If the model validates, where does the 504 come from?

Comment: The Kafka consumer has a loop to consume messages. I think maybe because it takes time and no response comes back as it is a continuous loop so the http request breaks. But breaks only on OpenShift not locally

Comment: Can you post your controller action?

Comment: `[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> StartKafkaConsumer([FromBody] KafkaInputConfigDTO kafkaInputConfigDTO) {
   return await _kafkaService.StartKafkaConsumer(kafkaInputConfigDTO);
  }`

Comment: I think it would be better for you to post these comments in your question.

Comment: 504 means server timeout.  Are you sure `StartKafkaConsumer` is actually returning?

Comment: Thanks @Neil I did add the code and log into my question. The `StartkafkaConsumer` does not return anything there I even tried with void and it did break even there. I was woundering if it is because of the certificates of the https redirection?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong technology.  A web server is not great for a message-bus architecture.  I wrote a Kafka service in C# last year and it was a console app, which meant it could be blocking or threaded as necessary.

Comment: @Neil ya I agree with you as I have a parallel project in the same sln with the same code but as a a console app. It works good. The idea was to make a web api so other ppl could use it and add their own consumers. As the console app cli not available in Openshift